# Why can the weak forms of the Stokes and continuity equations be combined into a single equation?

Tags: finite-element, fluid-dynamics, navier-stokes, incompressible

Consider this Stokes equations,
$$
\left\{
    \begin{array}{r}
        - \mu \Delta \vec{u} +  \nabla P  =  \vec{f}  \\
        \nabla \cdot \vec{u} = 0
    \end{array}
\right.
$$

Weak form I is:
$$
\left\{
    \begin{array}{r}
        {\color{red}{\mu <\nabla \phi, \nabla \vec{u} > -  <\nabla \cdot \phi,P>}} &=& {\color{red}{< \phi,\vec{f}>}}  \\
        {\color{blue}{<\psi,\nabla \cdot \vec{u}>}} &=& {\color{blue}{0}}
    \end{array}
\right.
$$

Weak form II is:
$$
{\color{red}{ \mu <\nabla \phi, \nabla \vec{u} > -  <\nabla \cdot \phi,P>}}  {\color{blue}{ -<\psi,\nabla \cdot \vec{u}>}} = {\color{red}{< \phi,\vec{f}>}}
$$

Why are the number of equations reduced, but Forms I and II are still equivalent?

Answer (score 5):

To get from weak form I to II, just add the two equations of weak form I.

To see the other direction, note that weak form II has to hold for all test functions $\phi$ and $\psi$. That is, you can test with $\phi = 0$ to obtain the  second part of weak form I. Similarly, testing with $\psi = 0$ yields the first part.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. So "it holds for all $\phi$ and all $\psi$." is equivalent to "it holds for all $\phi$ when $\psi = 0$, and holds for all $\psi$ when $\phi = 0 $.", right?

Comment: Another way to think about it is to notice that if $\langle \psi, \nabla\cdot u \rangle \neq 0$, the LHS of the combined weak form can be made arbitrarily large by varying just $\psi$ and the RHS remains fixed, so that term must be zero

Comment: @Hao, that's not mathematically equivalent (you only get one direction): If it holds for all $(\phi, \psi)$, then it holds for all $(\phi, 0)$ and $(0, \psi)$ in particular. In other words: If a statement is true for all points in a 2D plane, then it is also true for every line in the plane (i.e., the coordinate axes), because these are just subsets.

Comment: @cos_theta, I'm still a little confused. If it holds for the two base vectors and each (ϕ,ψ) is a linear combination of the two base vectors, the former should mathematically equivalent to the latter, shouldn't it? Perhaps, in this case, each point is not to be considered as a linear combination of base vectors?

Comment: You are correct, but you have to *show* that it works for all linear combinations. Showing that it works on just the basis elements is not enough